# Ansible playbook to check operating system

Tags: ansible

How do I check the installed operating system and proceed with the download of the file if system has Oracle Linux installed?

This is what I have so far:

````
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Check if oracle linux is installed
      shell: |
        cat: /etc/system-release
      register: os_name
      ignore_errors: yes
    - debug:
      msg: "{{os_name.stdout}}"```
````

Comment: Please see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts to get accustomed with discovered facts from target system and look for `ansible_distribution`

Answer (score 5):

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:     

     - name: downloading file if Oracle Linux is there
       get_url:
              url: #url of the file to download 
              dest: #path where you want to store it eg. /etc/downloaded-file
              mode: '0600' #permissions to be given to the file
       when: ansible_facts['distribution'] == "OracleLinux"
```

you may want to read this references.
1. [variable discover from system: Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts)
2. [Downloads files from HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP to node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html)

Comment: Thanks Shreyash,
I want to explicitly capture OS name from `cat /etc/system-release` and proceed if the system is Oracle Linux and ignore other operating system.

Comment: you will get the same output from ansible_lsb.description. which you are getting from the cat /etc/system-release. just try to add the debug statement

Answer (score 4):

You should use ansible `gather_facts: yes` output so that your ansible playbook is common across all platform, else reading `/etc/system-release` won't work on all platform.
[Refer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts)

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Distribution
      debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

> when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

```
  ---
    - name: install apache
      hosts: all
      become: yes
    
      vars:
        source_file: ./html-samples/site20/
        destin_file: /var/www/html
    
      tasks:
      - name: check OS version
        debug: var=ansible_os_family
    
    
      - block:     # for redhat
    
         - name: install apache web server for RedHat
           yum: name=httpd state=latest
    
         - name: copy web-site files to Apache web server
           copy: src={{ source_file }} dest={{ destin_file }} mode=0555
           notify: Restart Apache Restart Apache RedHat
    
         - name: start Apache and enable it on the boot for RedHat
           service: name=httpd state=started enabled=yes
    
        when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are correct.
If for some reasons (python being unavaible on your targeted host for example) you cannot/don't want to gather facts, here is the ugly way:

```
- hosts: whatever
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Register the system release
      raw: cat /etc/system-release
      register: system_release
      changed_when: no
      check_mode: no

    - name: Do something for Oracle systems
      ...
      when: "{{ system_release.stdout|trim is match('.*Oracle Linux.*') }}"
```

Comment: Python does not have to be available on the target host to run `gather_facts`.

Comment: This isn't particularly generic solution as /etc/system-release does not exist on many Debian based distributions  like Ubuntu , Rasbpian etc.