# How do I use Ansible facts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I see different ways of checking for the OS. Some use `ansible_facts["os_name"]` while others use `ansible_os_family`. Is there a preferred one to use?

Comment: _I see different ways of checking for the OS. Some use `ansible_facts["os_name"]`_ Do you have any reference for this? Where do you see such?

Comment: `ansible_os_name` is not returned on a linux host (at least not on my current Ubuntu station). I suspect it is specific to windows. You can also have a look at all `ansible_distribution_*` facts as well as the `ansible_lsb` dict (probably linux specific...). As a conclusion: there are plenty of facts you can use depending on your situation and how specific you want to be in your test. Just choose wisely the one(s) relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... others use `ansible_os_family`. Is there a preferred one to use?*

The documentation about [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) reference only [`os_family`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts).

Also [Getting full name of the OS using Ansible facts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035723/6771046) reference only `os_family`.

Based on that I would assume there is no such fact like `os_name`, can't be used therefore and `os_familiy` should be preferred.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible playbook to determine OS release](https://superuser.com/questions/1395954/)
- [Ansible Determine Operating System](https://superuser.com/questions/1010836/)
- [How to create Ansible playbook to obtain OS versions of Remote Hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078247/)
- [Ansible playbook to check Operating System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048600/)